# How can I count the hidden files in a directory using a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, grep

I have used this code

```
#!/bin/bash

ls -l
echo -n "Number of simple files : "
ls -l | egrep '^-' | wc -l 
echo -n "Number of directories : "
ls -l | egrep '^d' | wc -l
echo -n "Number of hidden files : "
ls -la | egrep '^.*\.$' | wc -l
echo -n "Number of hidden directories : "
ls -la | egrep '^d.*\.$' | wc -l
echo " End"
```

While I can understand how the first two egrep work I can't figure out how the last
two work. More specific what does this mean `'^.*\.$'` ?
I want a file that starts with . (hidden file) and then how I should shape my regular expression?

Comment: Now, if your *real* question is not how to count hidden files, but what the regex `^.*\.$` means, you should ask that as its own, separate question.

Comment: The last two don't work. They count the number of regular files and directories, respectively, whose names *end* with a period.

Comment: For any other folks in here, some links to the wiki maintained by the freenode #bash channel: [BashFAQ #4](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004) deals with a best-practices approach to counting files in general. [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) describes in detail why `ls` should not be used in this kind of use case, and alternatives available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex doesn't work, because `'^.*\.$'` matches the dot at the end of the line. Use these commands instead to count hidden files and directories:

```
ls -ld .* | egrep '^-' | wc -l
ls -ld .* | egrep '^d' | wc -l
```

Note that `egrep '^d'` matches `.` and `..` too, so you need subtract 2 from the result:

```
ls -ld .* | egrep '^d' | wc -l | awk '{print $1 - 2}'
```

Alternatives:

```
ls -ld .* | egrep '^d' | tail -n +3 | wc -l
echo $(($(ls -ld .* | egrep '^d' | wc -l) - 2))
```

Comment: the odd thing is that my example actually works, but i can't figure out why.

Comment: @Molnia I tested your code and it doesn't work for me. It always returns 2, because it matches `.` and `..`.

Comment: Yes i think you are right. That confused me earlier.

Comment: Why do you think that? What is the expected and the actual value?

Comment: i get 3 hidden directories but in fact i have only one. Perhaps, it counts the `.` and `..`

Comment: @Molnia Yes, it counts `.` and `..` too, because those are considered to be hidden directories too (name starts with `.`). You need to subtract 2 from the result, see my updated answer.

Comment: is there an variant without the usage of awk?

Comment: @Molnia Added two alternatives.

Comment: I hope this is provided to be informational, rather than to be legitimately representative of a best-practices approach for counting files.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This is one way to solve the problem. The document you linked is irrelevant here, `ls -l` can handle newlines.

Comment: I was seeking an answer similar to my code. That's why i posted specific code and i didn't ask in general.
@Charles Duffy thanks for the alternative solution, your answer appears to be the "best-practice" for a wider approach of my question.

Comment: @GergoErdosi, teaching folks that `ls -l | grep` is the right way to filter lists of files can (does, speaking with my #bash hat on) lead to people using that output in cases where it isn't appropriate or safe. Yes, it's safe to count lines (when output is not to a terminal, POSIX specifies that output must be one-line-per-file), but it's not safe to actually to extract and use names or metadata... and following the practice given here is not only inefficient from a performance perspective, but leaves folks in a position where such extraction is tempting, and *appears* safe and correct.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I see your point and agree with it. Upvoted your answer.

Comment: If you could edit in a caveat about not using this practice for anything other than counting, I think I'd see fit to modify my vote.

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't be using `grep` (or `ls`) for this task at all. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for an in-depth discussion of how `ls` should only **ever** be used for interactive display to humans.

```
all_files=( * )            # includes directories
directories=( */ )         # directories only
hidden_files=( .* )        # includes directories
hidden_directories=( .*/ ) # directories only

echo "Number of files: $(( ${#all_files[@]} - ${#all_directories[@]} ))"
echo "Number of directories: ${#directories[@]}"
echo "Number of hidden files: $(( ${#hidden_files[@]} - ${#hidden_directories[@]} ))"
echo "Number of hidden directories: $(( ${#hidden_directories[@]} - 2 ))"
```

The `- 2` in the last calculation is to remove `.` and `..`, which will always be present.

Comment: `$(( ${#all_files[@]} - ${#all_directories[@]})"` should be `$(( ${#all_files[@]} - ${#all_directories[@]} ))"` (missing parenthesis)

Comment: Thank you, jaypal, for making the edit suggested by @GergoErdosi

Answer (score 1):

Note that your approach of parsing `ls` output for this purpose is wrong. See @Dharles Duffy's answer for a better alternative. To answer your question though and explain the regex a little bit:

`'^.*\.$'` means

```
^     // From the beginning of the string
.*    // match zero or more of any character
\.    // match one literal full-stop
$     // end of the string
```

I am not sure what you mean with a "secret" file but if you mean a hidden file, i.e. one that begins with `.` and then a filename, the way to regex that would be

```
'^\..*$'
```

Note that this is not when parsing `ls` output and is just for a file or directory name and does not discern between the two.

Comment: yes, i am sorry i actually mean hidden.
I can't really understand why my example works for hidden files(it's not my code).
Yours example seems more logical.

Comment: No the last two regexes in your original post will always match and only match `.` and `..` which are the references for "this directory" and "parent directory" respectively. For that reason the result will always be 2 regardless of the folder you apply it to. In your case it might have been a coincidence that you had 2 hidden files and directories

Comment: i mean your solution `'^\..*$'`

Answer (score 1):

last two work incorrect, but

```
ls -la | egrep '^.*\.$' | wc -l
ls -la | egrep '^d.*\.$' | wc -l
```

`return 2`

```
ls -la | egrep '^.*\.$' 
ls -la | egrep '^d.*\.$'
```

return

```
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root  4096 date time .
drwxr-xr-x 31 root root  4096 date time ..
```

variant:

```
secret files:
ls -la | grep '^-' |awk '{print $9}' |egrep '^\.[^\.]' |wc -l
secret dirs:
ls -la | grep '^d' |awk '{print $9}' |egrep '^\.[^\.]' |wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find $THE_DIRECTORY -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '.*' | wc --lines
```

Should work, you may want to use -L if you want to find symlinks as well.

Comment: Why tell `find` to print actual names when you only want to count them? `-printf .` will let you count characters, or `-printf '\n'` will let you count lines with less data going through the pipeline and thus less inefficiency.

Comment: ...also, `wc --lines` only works on GNU systems, whereas `wc -l` works on any POSIX-compliant platform.

Comment: Why indeed? Thanks for the insights :)